# Create a boot flash disk to boot on a current Linux installation

Tags: boot, grub2, usb-drive

I have Pop OS installed on a partition of my hard disk and I would like to install another Linux distribution on another partition.

The other Linux distribution will install Grub2 and I am afraid of loosing access to my Pop OS.

How to create a USB disk just to boot on my current Pop OS installation?

Comment: You can do this, but then have to know how to add new distribution to SystemD boot if that is what you are using. If using grub2, you can just add boot entry for new install. This launches the installer program (Ubiquity) with an option (-b) to not install a boot loader from live installer in live mode:
In the Terminal window, type `ubiquity -b`. 
 Must be in same boot mode, usually UEFI now. New installs typically make themselves first in boot order, but grub adds other installs. Then you just need to change UEFI boot order or grub boot order to older install.

Comment: If your using grub add os-prober when you install grub and it will check for other boot partitions if your installing something like Ubuntu it will automatically do this.